# Is there any way to customize GPT3.5 model to use custom data without feeding it each time?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

I have custom data in my local and when I feed it to GPT3.5, I can get good answer from it.
But on next question without sending the all historic messages, I cannot get good answers.

Is there any way to append local data in GPT model to reduce cost?

Comment: Have you already looked into vector databases?

Comment: Yes, vector database can be good to answer some questions. But that approach is not good if the answer needs to be based on all context.

Comment: To allow me to help you better, can you add examples of what works well and what does not?

Comment: For example, there is a text "There are 3 apples, 2 oranges and 1 banana in the freezer".
And if I ask "What fruits do you have?" in vector db, it won't return above sentence because there is no matching text.
But if I send above context in GPT and ask the question, it'll return expected answer.